# Local bus schedule structure/design

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I'm Gergo Nagy, and I'm learning databases. My project is a bus schedule program, in android, but I stucked with the database part.
My program will include 2 main parts:
-If I click on a number of a bus, it shows the whole schedule, and a number, that shows when will the next bus start from the departure point.
-if I click on the address of the bus stop, it shows which buses crosses this stop. But it only shows that buses, which arrives in an hour.

My problem is the many-to-many database, because one bus has a lot of stops, but a stop "has" a lot of buses.
I'll attach a picture, from the schedule, I hope with this it will be easier to understand my question, 'cause my english is really bad, and sorry for that.
[image: Help for the question]

I know it's a mess, but with this level of english knowledge, it's my best.
I hope you can help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your engish isn't bad. Your problem  is sufficiently described. No need to apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bus schedule is actually much more complicated than just one many-to-many.  There are actually at least a couple of many-to-many relationships needed to record the data in the schedule chart you've shown.

Consider this ERD:

[image: ERD]

Here is the type of data that would go in each table:

- `BUS_NUMBER` has a bus #1.  Maybe this also has a name or other information.
- `BUS_ROUTE_TYPE` is where you have (1)a, (1)b, (1)c.  It is a child table of `BUS_NUMBER`. Maybe different bus numbers don't have a, b, and c. Some may only have a, some may have more than three, etc.
- `STOP` is the list of places where busses go, like Noszlopy G. park or Cifra Palota, etc.  Note that the route type has an original starting location (origin) and a finishing location (destination).  It also has a list of stops along the way, which are in `TRAVEL_TIME_OFFSET` (see next)
- `TRAVEL_TIME_OFFSET` is a many-to-many intersection between a bus route type (e.g. 1b) and the places where the bus goes. For each stop along the way, the number of minutes of travel time to that stop from the origin is recorded.  These are in your schedule chart as the numbers in circles on the left hand side. For example, for bus route 1b stop Piaristak tere is 0 minutes, Kodaly Iskola is 6 minutes, and Homokbanya kollegium is 15 minutes (including all the others along the way too)
- `SCHEDULE_TYPE` is the list of different starting times - for example on school days, in summer workdays, free days, etc.  These are the blocks of numbers on the right hand side of the chart (not the numbers in the blocks, the names of the blocks themselves)
- `DEPARTURE` is also a many-to-many intersection.  This is the list of times that a bus of a certain route type (e.g. 1c) leaves the origin stop, depending on what schedule type is in effect.  For example, in Non-Working Days, Bus Route Type 1c departs at 20:40 and 22:30.

**SAMPLE DATA**

Here is some sample table to illustrate how to use these tables.  I'm using meaningless (auto incremented) [Surrogate Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) for the tables because that's probably what you want to use.  I'm picking numbers for these to help make it clearer how records in one table join to others using primary and foreign keys.

```
BUS_NUMBER
==========
ID   CodeNumber Bus Route Name
---- ---------- --------------
33   1          Route 1
34   2          Route 2
...

BUS_ROUTE_TYPE
==============
ID   RouteTypeCode BusNumberID OriginStopID DestinationStopID Direction
---- ------------- ----------- ------------ ----------------- ---------
123  A             33          2345         2358              Out
124  B             33          2348         2358              Out
125  C             33          2345         2358              Out
126  A             33          2358         2345              Return
...

STOP
====
ID   Name
---- --------------------------------
2345 Noszlopy G. park
2346 Vasutallmmas
2347 Cifra Palota
2348 Piaristak tere
2349 Naiv Muveszeti Muzeum
2350 Katona J. Gimnazium
...
2357 Valyogveto utca
2358 Homokbanya kollegium

TRAVEL_TIME_OFFSET
==================
ID   BusRouteTypeID StopID Minutes
---- -------------- ------ -------
4567 123            2345   0
4568 123            2346   1
4569 123            2347   3
4570 123            2348   5
...
4579 123            2357   24
4580 123            2358   25

SCHEDULE_TYPE
=============
ID   Name 
---- ------------------------------
4    Iskolai eloadasi napokon
5    Tanszunetben munkanapokon
6    Szabadnapokon
7    Munkaszuneti napokon

DEPARTURE
=========
ID   ScheduleTypeID BusRouteTypeID StartTime
---- -------------- -------------- ---------
6123 4              125            04:35
6124 4              125            22:30
6125 4              124            04:40
6126 4              123            05:00
6126 4              123            05:15
6127 4              123            05:30
...
```

Comment: I've read this since 1 hour, but I there are a lot of questions in me.
First of all, you said "here is the type of data that would go in each table". 
How many tables I actually need? For the first reading, i thought these 6 blocks are 6 different tables. But then I realized, it won't work, because there are a lot of buses, and lot of stops too. For example, there is bus #2, with a totally different route, bus number 3, and so on. With this model, I need at least 30 tables for the 30 different busses. Am I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @GergőNagy I think you are totally misunderstanding how relational databases work.  There are six tables.  The `BUS_NUMBER` table will have one record for each bus number (1, 2, 3,...).  Similarly, every other table will have different records/rows for each bus schedule as necessary.  You have one set of tables with multiple sets of data in each table.  You should make sure that you understand how relational databases work and what foreign keys are and how to use them.

Comment: I learnt relational databases in school, but I think I do not understand well. So, if I have 46 different buses, and about 200 different stops, how do I know which is the route? I started develop the database, but I'M stucked here:
https://i.imgur.com/8vkROTP.png
I have all buses, and all 3 different childs (a,b,c), and all stops (from all different 46 buses). But for exdample starting times should be an Array, in programming, and in one table  there should be each array. 
I know it's basic, but after searching a day, I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: (here is the whole pdf with all schedules: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uE0mAUCwtlHelcq7hGMjA95y8UGCitS/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: @GergőNagy See the sample data I added to my answer. If there are 46 buses there will be 46 records in the `BUS_NUMBER` table.  Similarly 200 records in the `STOP` table. You know the route from the `TIME_TRAVEL_OFFSET`, which tells you for each route what stops are how many minutes away from the origin.  You can sort by the number of minutes (ascending) to get a list of the stops in the correct sequence.  Tables are more complex than arrays.  You can think of a two dimensional array as like a table. Think more about a spreadsheet than an array and it might be clearer.

Comment: I tried a simple query, where STOP.Name = "something", but it returned zero values. What is the problem about this query?
SELECT a.CodeNumber
FROM bus_number a, departure b, bus_route_type c, stop d, schedule_type e, travel_time_offset f
 WHERE a.bus_id=c.BusNumberID AND b.BusRouteTypeID=c.ID AND b.ScheduleTypeID=e.ID AND c.OriginStopID=d.ID AND c.id=f.BusRouteTypeID AND d.ID=f.StopID 
 AND e.ID=1 AND d.StopName LIKE "Veres Péter u."

Comment: @GergőNagy It's not clear what is wrong with your query, except that it will usually return ambiguous results because you're joining two different ways between STOP and ROUTE_TYPE (once direct by origin, once indirect through TRAVEL TIME OFFSET).  Also, you have "like _specific literal_" in your where clause.  I'm inclined to think that your data doesn't match your expectations.  Did you try running this query: `select * from STOP where StopName LIKE "Veres Péter u."`  Similarly, is there a SCHEDULE_TYPE ID=1?

Comment: your query returned 4 lines, and yes, there's a schedule_type id=0.
I tried this: [code]SELECT a.CodeNumber FROM bus_number a, bus_route_type c, stop d WHERE a.bus_id=c.BusNumberID AND c.OriginStopID=d.ID AND c.DestinationStopID=d.ID AND d.StopName="Veres Péter u."[code]  but it also returned with nothing.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, finally I realized the problem. In bus_route_type table, the OriginStopID is the id where the bus starts, the DestinationStopID is the last stop of the route. And between these two numbers, there is the stopid, what I'm looking for. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have these entities to convert in tables.

I suggest you build the fallowing tables in excel and see if all is there or something missing.

**Stations** : has name , and id .

**Routes** : connect stations and defines the bus time from one to another station.

**Bus_and_start**: when will every buss start and what route. Do you have a list of buses , like buss_long1 , bus_short1 , bus_extralarge4 ? Then split this table in 2 , the bus table and the start table. This would be good if a bus breaks or if you monitor real time if is to slow . Real_time monitoring will bring a list of challenges, not sure if this is part of your project.

To see for a station the next hour bus , you take all the routes that stop in that station and join with all bus_and_start and the route time to the bus start time and here is the list. If you need help , define the tables and I will help with the SQL statement.

Comment: note the Bus_and_start will have a field for 'school,summer,free,nonwork'

Comment: real_time monitoring isn't the part (now). I started wrote these to excel, but I think it doesn't look too good.  I tried to store these in Access, but I haven't finished yet. (Because my the table defining problem)